# zsh/bash source command behavior difference

Tags: zsh

I am trying to source a third party script  in `zsh` (named `setup_env.sh` stored in `~/`), that has following lines in the beginning to guard against accidental execution:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Guard the script against execution - it must be sourced!
echo $0 | egrep 'setup_env.sh' > /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
echo ""
echo "ERROR: the setup file must be SOURCED, NOT EXECUTED in a shell."
echo "Try (for bash)  : source setup_env.sh"
echo "Or (eg. for ksh): . setup_env.sh"
exit 1
fi

# export some environment variables
...
```

When I source this script with `source ~/setup_env.sh`, I see the error message shown in the above code block.

From the script it's apparently visible that it's not written with `zsh` in mind. But I still want to know why `zsh` behaves this way, and if it's possible to source the script as it is.

I could source the script as it is without error using `bash`. 
I could also source it in `zsh` after commenting out the guard block in the beginning of the script.

Can someone explain this difference in behavior for `source` command between `zsh` and `bash`?

Comment: Probably because `.` and `source` in zsh support additional arguements, but it does not in bash or ksh. IMO that check is poorly implemented.

Comment: @jordanm Both `bash` and `ksh` support passing arguments to the sourced file.

Comment: The easiest fix would just be to strip that kind of hand-holding from the script.

Answer (score 2):

zsh/bash have different ways to detect sourcing, following should work for both :

```
if  [[ -n  $ZSH_VERSION && $ZSH_EVAL_CONTEXT == toplevel ]] || \
    [[ -n $BASH_VERSION && $BASH_SOURCE      == $0       ]]; then
    echo "Not sourced"
    exit 1
fi
```

To explain a little more, when you run :

```
source setup_env.sh
# setup_env.sh containing "echo $0"
```

In  zsh, $0 == setup_env.sh

In bash, $0 == bash